# limit of sequence of cdf that has limit at infinity not 1

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, analysis

Let $F_n$ be sequence of cumulative distribution functions, $D$ be dense set in $R$, $F_n(t)$ converge to $F(t)$ for all $t$ in $D$. Then F_n(t) converges at every point of continuity of $F$, however may not be cdf due to the fact that limit at infinity of $F$ may be less than $1$.

Can you give me example of such sequence?

Comment: Hint: look for an example where $F(t)$ is identically $0$. (This can come from an example of "losing mass at infinity", if that phrase is familiar to you.)

Comment: $F_n(x)=0$ on $(-\infty,0)$, $\frac{x}{n}$ on $[0,n]$, $1$ on $(n,\infty)$